# how to check if any of given queries return any result in knex

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I have two queries:

a) `select id from ingredietns where name = my_param;`

b) `select word_id from synonyms where name = my_param;`

Both return 0 or 1 row. I can also add `limit 1` if needed (or in knex `first()`).

I can translate each into knex like this:

```
knex("ingredients").select('id').where('name', my_param) //do we need first()?

knex("synonyms").select('word_id').where('name', my_param) //do we need first()?
```

I need function called "`ingredientGetOrCreate(my_param)`". This function would

a) check if any of above queries return result
b) if any of these return, then return ingredients.id or synonyms.word_id - only one could be returned 
c) if record doesn't eixst in any of tables, I need to do knex inesrt aand return newly added id from function

d) later I am not sure I also understand how to call this newly create function.
Function `ingredientGetOrCreate` would be used later as seperate function or in the following scenario (like "loop") that doesn't work for me either:

```
knex("products") // for each product
    .select("id", "name")
    .map(function (row) {
        var descriptionSplitByCommas = row.desc.split(",");
        Promise.all(descriptionSplitByCommas
            .map(function (my_param) {
                // here it comes - call method for each param and do insert
                ingredientGetOrCreate(my_param)
                  .then(function (id_of_ingredient) {
                          knex('ingredients_products').insert({ id_of_ingredient });                      

                  });
         ...
```

I am stuck with `knex` and `Promise` queries because of asynchronouse part. Any clues, please?
I though I can somehow use `Promise.all` or `Promise.some` to call both queries.

P.S. This is my first day with nodejs, Promise and knex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I decode your question, it consists of two parts:

(1) You need to implement `upsert` logic (`get-or-create` logic).

(2) Your `get` part requires to query not a single table, but a pair of tables in specific order. Table names imply that this is some sort of aliasing engine inside of your application.

Let's start with (2). This could definitely be solved with two queries, just like you sense it.

```js
function pick_name (rows)
{
    if (! rows.length) return null
    return rows[0].name
}

// you can sequence queries
function ingredient_get (name)
{
    return knex('ingredients')
    .select('id').where('name', name)
    .then(pick_name)
    .then(name =>
    {
        if (name) return name

        return knex('synonyms')
        .select('word_id').where('name', name)
        .then(pick_name)
    })
}

// or run em parallel
function ingredient_get (name)
{
    var q_ingredients = knex('ingredients')
    .select('id').where('name', name)
    .then(pick_name)

    var q_synonyms = knex('synonyms')
    .select('word_id').where('name', name)
    .then(pick_name)

    return Promise.all([ q_ingredients, q_synonyms ])
    .then(([name1, name2]) =>
    {
       return name1 || name2
    })
}
```

Important notions here:

- Both forms works well and return first occurence or JS' `null`.
- First form optimizes count of queries to DB.
- Second form optimizes answer time.

However, you can go deeper and use more SQL. There's a special tool for such task called `COALESCE`. You can consult your SQL documentation, here's [COLASCE of PostgreSQL 9](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL). The main idea of `COALESCE` is to return first non-NULL argument or NULL otherwise. So, you can leverage this to optimize both queries and answer time.

```js
function ingredient_get (name)
{
    // preparing but not executing both queries
    var q_ingredients = knex('ingredients')
    .select('id').where('name', name)

    var q_synonyms = knex('synonyms')
    .select('word_id').where('name', name)

    // put them in COALESCE
    return knex.raw('SELECT COALESCE(?, ?) AS name', [ q_ingredients, q_synonyms ])
    .then(pick_name)
```

This solution guarantees single query and furthermore DB engine can optimize execution in any way it sees appropriate.

Now let's solve (1): We now got `ingredient_get(name)` which returns `Promise<string | null>`. We can use its output to activate `create` logic or return our value.

```js
function ingredient_get_or_create (name, data)
{
    return ingredient_get(name)
    .then(name =>
    {
       if (name) return name

       // …do your insert logic here
       return knex('ingredients').insert({ name, ...data }) 
       // guarantee homohenic output across get/create calls:
       .then(() => name)
    })
}
```

Now `ingredient_get_or_create` do your desired upsert logic.

**UPD1**:
We already got `ingredient_get_or_create` which returns `Promise<name>` in any scenario (both get or create).

a) If you need to do any specific logic after that you can just use `then`:

```js
ingredient_get_or_create(…)
.then(() => knex('another_table').insert(…))
.then(/* another logic after all */)
```

In promise language that means «do that action (`then`) if previous was OK (`ingredient_get_or_create`)». In most of the cases that is what you need.

b) To implement for-loop in promises you got multiple different idioms:

```js
// use some form of parallelism
var qs = [ 'name1', 'name2', 'name3' ]
.map(name =>
{
   return ingredient_get_or_create(name, data)
})

var q = Promise.all(qs)
```

Please, note, that this is an agressive parallelism and you'll get maximum of parallel queries as your input array provides.

If it's not desired, you need to limit parallelism or even run tasks sequentially. Bluebird's [Promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) is a way to run `map` which analogous to example above but with `concurrency` option available. Consider the docs for details.

There's also Bluebird's [Promise.mapSeries](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html) which conceptually is an analogue to for-loop but with promises. It's like map which runs sequentially. Look the docs for details.

```js
Promise.mapSeries([ 'name1', 'name2', 'name3' ],
(name) =>  ingredient_get_or_create(name, data))
.then(/* logic after all mapSeries are OK */)
```

I believe the last is what you need.

Comment: It seems that it works. Can you please help me one more thing: what if a) after ingredient_get_or_create I need to run one more insert? b) i need this to be run in "a for loop" (in Promise language it would not be for loop). I have updated my question - see at the end.